# How do I change the placeholder in comment field?

Tags: blogger, placeholder

The default placeholder in the comment box of Blogger is a very ugly "Enter your comment here..."  I would like to change the text and style it a little to match my blog.

However, I can't figure out how to do that.  These are the only two places the HTML lists "comment-holder":

> var render = function() {
>           if (window.goog && window.goog.comments) {
>             var holder = document.getElementById('comment-holder');
>             window.goog.comments.render(holder, provider);
>
> div class='comments-content'>
>         b:if cond='data:post.embedCommentForm'>
>           
>         /b:if>
>         div id='comment-holder'>
>            data:post.commentHtml/>
>         /div>

I am fairly new to CSS and HTML, so please be gentle with me. If there is more information that you need from me, just let me know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The comment form is in a `iframe` outside of the user domain, so I think it's not possible to change the comment form.